# ConcurrentModificationException al iterar sobre una lista

Tags: java, java-swing, bucles

Me salta una **ConcurrentModificationException** al iterar sobre una lista: `List<Attribute> attributes` esta lista contiene objetos de tipo **Attribute**, que serán usados para la creación de vistas **AttributeView**:

El metodo que uso para crear las vistas:

```
public void createAttributeViews(List<Attribute> attributes) {
        if (attributes.size() != -1) { //La lista debe contener elementos
            Iterator<Attribute> iter = attributes.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Attribute attribute = iter.next();
                AttributeView view = new AttributeView(attribute);
                mainPanel.add(view.getMainPanel()); //añade la vista al panel principal
            }
        }
    }
```

El error lo recibo en la linea: **`Attribute attribute = iter.next();`** all llamar **`iter.next()`**

La lista que paso como parametro en el metodo **`public void createAttributeViews(List<Attribute> attributes)`** la inizializzo de esta manera:

```
protected void init(User user) {
    List<Attribute> userAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
    userAttributes.addAll(userAttributeService.getUserAttributesById(user.getId()));
    createAttributeViews(userAttributes);
}
```

A que se debe el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue crear otra lista en la clase que contiene el metodo **createAttributeViews()** e inizializzarla con los valores de la lista pasada como parametro usando **addAll()**:

```
public class MyClass{

private List<Attribute> attribute = new ArrayList<>();

...............

public void createAttributeViews(List<Attribute> attributes) {
this.attributes.addAll(attributes);
        if (attributes.size() != -1) { //La lista debe contener elementos
            Iterator<Attribute> iter = this.attributes.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Attribute attribute = iter.next();
                AttributeView view = new AttributeView(attribute);
                mainPanel.add(view.getMainPanel()); //añade la vista al panel principal
            }
        }
    }
```

Con el uso de esta otra lista el problema no se presenta.